# how can i set the source in a flutter application between camera or gallery?

Tags: image, flutter

i need help with my flutter application.
is there any way to figure out which button i press?
I'll explain.
In a page of my application I need to upload an image either from the gallery or from the camera.
What if I wanted to use a single function that, based on the button I press, sets the source in ImageSource.camera or ImageSource.gallery?
I am using ImagePicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_img( ImageSource.gallery);
_img( ImageSource.camera);

_img(source) async {
        try {
          _imageFile = null;
          final PickedFile file =
          await _picker.getImage(source:source, imageQuality: 50);
        //  _bytes = Io.File(file.path).readAsBytesSync();
        //  bytesData(file);
          setState(() {
            _imageFile = file;
    
    
          });
        } catch (e) {
          _pickImageError = e;
        }
      }
```